# Удалить все слова с удвоенными буквами

Tags: c++

Нужно использовать strtok, я не могу понять как мне проверить каждое слово из введённого массива символов, допустим:

```
char text[80];
cin.get(text, 80);
char *word = strtok(text, " ,.-?!");
while(text != 0)
{
    word = strtok(NULL, " ,.-?!");
}
```

Я понимаю, что мне в каждом слове нужно проверить предшествующий символ с последующим, но не могу понять как мне это правильно реализовать.

Comment: Что значит "проверить"?

Comment: допустим, есть строка "ноччь или день", стрток мне отрезает слово ноччь и я проверяю не равен ли первый символ второму, второй третьему и так дальше. Если они совпадают я удаляю слово

Comment: @MovieZ  Если вы собираетесь удалять слово из строки, то вам не следует использовать strtok,

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow а что надо использовать?

Comment: @MovieZ Нужно использовать друго1 подход. Кстати сказать, а почему у вас тире является разделителем слов? Обычно слова, записанные через тире, рассматриваются как одно слово. Вместо тире, вы могли бы в разделители включить двоеточие и точку с запятой.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow это чисто для примера, пока я только непонимаю, как проверять каждое отдельное слово, надо ведь узнавать сколько в нём символов?

Comment: В слове `strlen(word)` символов :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не следует использовать функцию `strtok`, так как она изменяет исходную строку, и вам будет сложно из нее удалить слова с повторяющимися символами. Вам нужно самостоятельно сканировать исходную строку либо в цикле либо с использованием таких функций как `strcspn` и `strspn` и находить начало и конец слова в предложении.

Определить, содержит ли слово смежные повторяющиеся символы достаточно просто. Можно для этого написать простой цикл либо использовать стандартный алгоритм `std::adjacent_find`, объявленный в заголовке `<algorithm>`. Вот фрагмент кода, который демонстрирует, как это можно сделать первым или вторым способом

Предполагается, что слово в строке уже найдено, и начало слова содержится в переменной `first`, а первый символ после слова - в переменной `last`/

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

char s[] = "abc abbc";

size_t first = 0;
size_t last = 3;

while (++first != last && s[first] != s[first - 1]) ++first;

if (first == last) std::cout << "There is no adjacent equal characters" << std::endl;
else std::cout << "The word contains adjacent equal characters" << std::endl;

first = 0;
last = 3;

if (std::adjacent_find(s + first, s + last) == s + last)
{
    std::cout << "There is no adjacent equal characters" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "The word contains adjacent equal characters" << std::endl;
}

first = 4;
last = 8;

while (++first != last && s[first] != s[first - 1]) ++first;

if (first == last) std::cout << "There is no adjacent equal characters" << std::endl;
else std::cout << "The word contains adjacent equal characters" << std::endl;

first = 4;
last = 8;

if (std::adjacent_find(s + first, s + last) == s + last)
{
    std::cout << "There is no adjacent equal characters" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "The word contains adjacent equal characters" << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод этого фрагмента кода будет выгляджеть следующим образом

```
There is no adjacent equal characters
There is no adjacent equal characters
The word contains adjacent equal characters
The word contains adjacent equal characters
```

Как видно из вывода, оба подхода, использование вручную написанного цикла или использование стандартного алгоритма, дают один и тот же результат.

Теперь, зная начало и конец слова, вы можете уделить его из строки простым копированием подстроки, следующей за найденным словом в начальную позицию слова, тем самым "затирая" слово.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше работать вот так:

```
for(char * s = strtok(text," ,.-?!"); s; s = strtok(nullptr," ,.-?!"))
{
    // Работаем с очередным словом s
}
```